# Jquery content slider based on php array

Tags: jquery, arrays, object, slider, containers

I have a problem building a slider container based on an array of object.
After calling a json content via curl - php i get a page like this:

```
<div id ="slider" class="grid">
  <!-- one -->
  <div class="top"></div>
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
  <div class="bottom"></div>
  <!-- two -->
  <div class="top"></div>
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
  <div class="bottom"></div>
  <!-- three -->
  <div class="top"></div>
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
  <div class="bottom"></div>
  <!-- many... -->
  <div class="top"></div>
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
  <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

I need to cycle through these elements with a slideshow, where each slide shows the four divs togheter (top, left, right, bottom). Could someone put me in the right way?
Many thanks.

UPDATE:
After looking around i found out what seems solution/workaroud:
it's related to this post [Wrapping sets of elements from a list in DIVs using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20386796/wrapping-sets-of-elements-from-a-list-in-divs-using-jquery) and comes with a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/QWHYK/.
I wrapped all my divs with a span tag and used that one line of code to wrap the elements (i was unable to use 'div' instead of 'span' in the jquery code, so i made:

```
<div id="slider" class="grid>
  <!-- one -->
  <span><div class="top"></div></span>
  <span><div class="left"></div></span>
  <span><div class="right"></div></span>
  <span><div class="bottom"></div></span>
 <!-- continue .... -->
```

```
while ($('#slider > span').length) {
$('#slider > span:lt(4)').wrapAll('<div class="row slide" />');
}
```

and i got this:

```
<div id="slider" class="grid>
  <!-- one -->
  <div class="row slide">
        <span><div class="top"></div></span>
        <span><div class="left"></div></span>
        <span><div class="right"></div></span>
        <span><div class="bottom"></div></span>
  </div>
  <!-- continue... -->
</div>
```

this the best that I could do in a short time.

Comment: Please make [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: There's a link in the UPDATE text to the original jsfiddle from where i took the code: http://jsfiddle.net/QWHYK/

Comment: @Prashant I made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uomopalese/N8ceA/) ;). Check the rsult with firebug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you would probably need to do is to find a way to wrap each one of those collections of four divs into a wrapper div. Give each one of those wrapper divs a class called .slide or something.

Are you able to get to that point? After that it shouldn't be too hard to implement a slider. There are lots of plugins able to do that. Have you considered something like Slick Carousel: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ – Looks like Demo 2 might be exactly what you need.

Hope that helps,
Marc

Comment: Thanks for encouragement ;). Now i can give a try to Slick.